# Query does not get data from table

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is that when I run the query in MySQL directly it works:

```
SELECT * FROM SubCategoryLookup  WHERE LinkedCategoryID = '4' AND OrganizationCode = 'ibm'
```

While using PHP, if I give any variable then it does not get records:

```
$OrganizationCode=$_REQUEST['OrganizationCode'];
echo($OrganizationCode);

$CategoryId=$_REQUEST['CategoryId'];
echo($CategoryId);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT *
                        FROM SubCategoryLookup
                       WHERE LinkedCategoryID = '$CategoryId'
                             AND OrganizationCode = '$OrganizationCode'");
echo($query);

$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

When I access this using URL:

http://www.celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/getSubCategory.php?OrganizationCode=celeritasCategoryId=3

Below is the result it does not show records

```
celeritasCategoryId=3Resource id #3[]
```

Comment: @Prix still same showing this result when i remove echo query celeritasCategoryId=1Array ( ) []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `&` on your URL, should be:

```
http://www.celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/getSubCategory.php?OrganizationCode=celeritas&CategoryId=3
```

With a closer look you have:

```
OrganizationCode=celeritasCategoryId=3
```

And it should have been:

```
OrganizationCode=celeritas&CategoryId=3
```

Which causes `$CategoryId` to be unset (or in other words empty) which makes your query fail and give you no result.

You should make use of [**`isset`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to make sure your variables are set:

```
$OrganizationCode = $_GET['OrganizationCode'];
if (!isset($OrganizationCode))
    die("There is no organization code...");

$CategoryId = $_GET['CategoryId'];
if (!isset($CategoryId))
    die("There is no category id...");
```

As well as sanitizing it to prevent injections using [**`mysql-real-escape-string`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and properly using error handlers to know if the query failed with [**`mysql_error`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php):

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * 
                  FROM SubCategoryLookup 
                 WHERE LinkedCategoryID='%s' AND 
                       OrganizationCode='%s'",
               mysql_real_escape_string($CategoryId),
               mysql_real_escape_string($OrganizationCode));

$query = mysql_query($sql);

// change $link to the name of your database connection variable
if (!$query)
    die('Query failed (' . mysql_errno($link) . '): ' . mysql_error($link));
```

---

There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

---

And here is what you will get:

```
 [{
     "SubCategoryID": "8",
     "LinkedCategoryID": "3",
     "SubCategoryTitle": "Projects: Client A",
     "SubCategoryAddedDateTime": "2013-07-12 23:16:25",
     "SubCategoryAddedByUserID": "1",
     "OrganizationCode": "celeritas"
 }, {
     "SubCategoryID": "9",
     "LinkedCategoryID": "3",
     "SubCategoryTitle": "Projects: Client B",
     "SubCategoryAddedDateTime": "2013-07-12 23:16:25",
     "SubCategoryAddedByUserID": "1",
     "OrganizationCode": "celeritas"
 }, {
     "SubCategoryID": "10",
     "LinkedCategoryID": "3",
     "SubCategoryTitle": "Projects: Client C",
     "SubCategoryAddedDateTime": "2013-07-12 23:16:25",
     "SubCategoryAddedByUserID": "1",
     "OrganizationCode": "celeritas"
 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your $rows array is right.
Print it before you execute json_encode.

Remove your array assignment code and add this

```
array_push($rows,$row)
```

Then print $rows

Comment: Yes. You can also use this for formated printing.
echo "<pre>";print_r($rows);"<pre>";

Comment: here is the result celeritasCategoryId=1Resource id #3Array ( ) []